# Running a method from an object in another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, libgdx, kryonet

I have LibGDX Application in which I paint and a Thread for Client or Server. Connections are done using Kryonet. When your opponent creates does something a message is recieved linke so:

```
public void received(Connection con, Object object) {

                            TroopMessage tm = (TroopMessage)object;                         
                            fortress.map.addSoldier(tm.kind, true);
                            System.out.println("recieved");

                            connection = con;
}
```

When this callback is called (and it is correctly) I get "No OpenGL context found in the current thread". I think it is looking for the object fortress within the MyClient Thread. I want to call to fortress.map.addSoldier which refers to an object currently existing in another thread.

```
public class Fortress extends Game implements ApplicationListener{
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batcher;

    public static MyServer server;
    public static MyClient client;

    public static Map map;
[....]
```

How can I call the method in from another thread?

thanks in advance

Comment: An `Object` does not belong to or exist in a specific thread, so that is not the problem here.

Comment: Have you tried searching? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347340/no-opengl-context-found-in-the-current-thread-how-do-i-fix-this-error

Comment: Yes I have seen that SO but they talk about "So you can only access this context from the same thread". How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

In Libgdx you can use `Gdx.app.postRunnable(Runnable r)` to ask the main OpenGL-context-having render thread to run some code.  See the Libgdx wiki about application threading here: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationThreading

As the comments point out, generally Java objects are not "owned" by a thread.  The "OpenGL context" is something of an exception to this, as only one thread is allowed to make changes to the OpenGL state.