# How to create an object every 3 seconds using a thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, object

I am trying to make a game where an enemy object spawns every 3 seconds and tries to chase your player, but I don't know how I will make a generator that creates an enemy object every 3 seconds.

I already tried this by creating a thread that runs every 3 seconds, but it gives me an error that says

> No OpenGL context found in the current thread.

I'm using OpenGL to program displays and textures.

Comment: Don't use `Thread` for this purpose. It is use case of `javax.swing.Timer`. Try some code with timers, and if you had any problem post your code here. Without a code there is little chance for getting good answers.

Comment: Timer can provide an event every `n` second, and in the listener of that event, you can make your spawns instances.

Comment: thanks! I'll try to search about timers and try to use them. :)

Comment: oh, and i don't think i can add the code here because it has alot of classes and its VERY messy... but ill try my best to figure out how i should do it! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No OpenGL context is current in the current thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992781/no-opengl-context-is-current-in-the-current-thread)

Comment: my problem is a little bit different because i need multiple threads that needs to create the enemies (there will be multiple types of enemies) but luckily i found my own way to fix this problem thanks to the other two people :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `ScheduletExecutorService` and [schedule at fixed rate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) every 3 seconds.
It will not create a new thread every 3 seconds, instead it uses only one additional thread to create all the objects you need.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // Create your object;
    }
}, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

To see more:

- [Executors from Oracle web site](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html)
- [An introduction to the Executor framework](https://dzone.com/articles/the-executor-framework) written by me on Dzone
- [A complete tutorial on executors](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

Comment: I add some resource on the answer where you can start your research

Comment: okay ;) didn't see that there was a "To see more: " under the answer. ill search there.