# Error Code 0x502 on Lwjgl Startup

Tags: java, lwjgl

When starting Lwjgl I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no OpenGL context current in the current thread.at 
org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.createCapabilities(GL.java:363)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.createCapabilities(GL.java:312)
    at rr.industries.OpenGLTest.<init>(OpenGLTest.java:42)
    at rr.industries.OpenGLTest.main(OpenGLTest.java:97)
```

When looking for answers for this everything said to either use `GLContext.createFromCurrent()`, which no longer exists in Lwjgl 3.1.2, or to add `GL.createCapabilities()` to your code, which was the command that was creating this error. I enabled debug mode on Lwjgl and I got this error:

```
[LWJGL] An OpenGL context was in an error state before the creation of its capabilities instance. Error: 0x502
```

I tried restarting my IDE and my computer. What can I do to troubleshoot / fix this.

**EDIT:**
After doing some trouble shooting this is not the root of the problem. If I completely avoid starting Lwjgl and don't call `GL.createCapabilities()` I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create the GLFW window
    at rr.industries.OpenGLTest.<init>(OpenGLTest.java:49)
    at rr.industries.OpenGLTest.main(OpenGLTest.java:102)
```

at this point I have no idea what is wrong. I checked that my drivers were updated and GL Viewer says my gpu supports OpenGL 3.0 - 4.4. Here is the code I am using (mostly copied from Lwjgl Getting Started page)

```
public class OpenGLTest {

    private long window;

    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OpenGLTest.class);

    public OpenGLTest(){
        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( !glfwInit() )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure GLFW
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);


        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(300, 300, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window"); //Stacktrace points to THIS line

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (window, key, scancode, action, mods) -> {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in the rendering loop
        });
    }

    public void start(){
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.

        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        loop();
        finish();
    }

    public void finish(){
        // Free the window callbacks and destroy the window
        glfwFreeCallbacks(window);
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);

        // Terminate GLFW and free the error callback
        glfwTerminate();
        glfwSetErrorCallback(null).free();
    }

    public void loop(){
        while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose(window) ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Configuration.DEBUG.set(true);
        GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.out);
        LOG.info("Starting Lwjgl v{}", Version.version());
        new OpenGLTest()/*.start()*/;
    }
}
```

`start()`, `loop()`, and `finish()` are never called trying to find the root of the problem. When I run the above code I always get the RuntimeException posted earlier. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No OpenGL context is current in the current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992781/no-opengl-context-is-current-in-the-current-thread)

Comment: The above link should solve the issue for you, but if not, then you need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but you could try changing the constructor in the class to a method and then calling that method in the start method before gl.createCapabilities as in the main method you are calling that start method but not the constructor. This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: The no context exception means no window to render on. Call the start method at the main method which has the constructor (changed to method) In it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `glfwMakeContextCurrent(window)` anywhere;